# How do I fix Toast not showing up due to null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, csv, toast

Whenever I load my emulator with the code it pulls up successfully and doesn't crash. I'm able to click on the buttons but they just wont load the Toast message. The Toast is supposed to pull the price from my listing file after pressing one of four buttons but nothing happens. Not sure where the error is.

I've tried using check id method `(id == R.id.button3)` but it doesn't match with the condition `property != null`. I've done other methods too but nothing works.

NOTE : Notifications are enabled in the emulator.

MainActivity :

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   
    private Listing listing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listing = new Listing();
        listing.loadProperties("listings.csv");

        // connecting buttons with the
        // layout using findViewById()
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);

        // apply setOnClickListener over buttons
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    // common onClick() for all buttons

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
        String location = clickedButton.getText().toString();
        Property property = listing.getProperty(location);

        if (property != null) {
            // Display property price in a Toast message
            String priceText = "Price: $" + property.getPrice();
            Toast.makeText(this, priceText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Property :

```java
public abstract class Property {
    private String ID;
    private String location;
    private double price;

    public Property(String ID, String location, double price) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.location = location;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + ID + "\nLocation: " + location + "\nPrice: " + price;
    }
}
```

CProperty :

```java
public class CommercialProperty extends Property {
    private String zone;
    private int numUnits;
    private int numParkingSpots;

    public CommercialProperty(String ID, String location, double price, String zone, int numUnits, int numParkingSpots) {
        super(ID, location, price);
        this.zone = zone;
        this.numUnits = numUnits;
        this.numParkingSpots = numParkingSpots;
    }

    // Getters and Setters for CommercialProperty-specific properties
    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public int getNumUnits() {
        return numUnits;
    }

    public void setNumUnits(int numUnits) {
        this.numUnits = numUnits;
    }

    public int getNumParkingSpots() {
        return numParkingSpots;
    }

    public void setNumParkingSpots(int numParkingSpots) {
        this.numParkingSpots = numParkingSpots;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\nZone: " + zone + "\nUnits: " + numUnits + "\nParking Spots: " + numParkingSpots;
    }
}
```

RProperty :

```java
public class ResidentialProperty extends Property {
    private double annualHoaFees;
    private int numBedrooms;
    private double numBathrooms;

    public ResidentialProperty(String ID, String location, double price, double annualHoaFees, int numBedrooms, double numBathrooms) {
        super(ID, location, price);
        this.annualHoaFees = annualHoaFees;
        this.numBedrooms = numBedrooms;
        this.numBathrooms = numBathrooms;
    }

    // Getters and Setters for ResidentialProperty-specific properties
    public double getAnnualHoaFees() {
        return annualHoaFees;
    }

    public void setAnnualHoaFees(double annualHoaFees) {
        this.annualHoaFees = annualHoaFees;
    }

    public int getNumBedrooms() {
        return numBedrooms;
    }

    public void setNumBedrooms(int numBedrooms) {
        this.numBedrooms = numBedrooms;
    }

    public double getNumBathrooms() {
        return numBathrooms;
    }

    public void setNumBathrooms(double numBathrooms) {
        this.numBathrooms = numBathrooms;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\nAnnual HOA Fees: " + annualHoaFees + "\nBedrooms: " + numBedrooms + "\nBathrooms: " + numBathrooms;
    }
}
```

Listing :

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Listing {
   
    private ArrayList<Property> properties;

    public Listing() {
        properties = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void loadProperties(String fileName) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("listings.csv"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(" ");
                if (data.length >= 6) {
                    String ID = data[0];
                    String location = data[1] + " " + data[2] + " " + data[3];
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(data[4]);

                    if (ID.startsWith("rp")) {
                        double annualHoaFees = Double.parseDouble(data[5]);
                        int numBedrooms = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);
                        double numBathrooms = Double.parseDouble(data[7]);
                        ResidentialProperty rp = new ResidentialProperty(ID, location, price, annualHoaFees, numBedrooms, numBathrooms);
                        properties.add(rp);
                    } else if (ID.startsWith("cp")) {
                        String zone = data[5];
                        int numUnits = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);
                        int numParkingSpots = Integer.parseInt(data[7]);
                        CommercialProperty cp = new CommercialProperty(ID, location, price, zone, numUnits, numParkingSpots);
                        properties.add(cp);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Property getProperty(String address) {
        for (Property prop : properties) {
            if (prop.getLocation().equals(address)) {
                return prop;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more relevant tags. The title combined with the single `java` tag makes it difficult for people to determine what you're having a problem *with*, and it's a lot less likely that someone will help you.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint? Is the toast called, or is `property == null`? I cannot see anything where the text of the buttons is set, but you are basically using the buttons text as source  for `if (prop.getLocation().equals(address))`

Comment: I'm very much new to this, so I might not give the best answers. property == null just crashes the app, I named the buttons in the the activity_main.xml file, and I'm not sure what else I could do besides use (prop.getLocation().equals(address)). The app opens with this code and runs fine, it just wont load the Toast popup.

Comment: I've even used differents versions of the code not using the csv file included and they work so I know its not some sort of permission or formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your

```
if (property != null)
```

Condition is not fulfilled.

There may some cases for this
may be the `location` string you get from clicked `Button` is not found in your `"listings.csv"` file.